# If two discrete finite random variables have equal moments up to $k$, does that imply all moments are equal?

Tags: probability, random-variables

If we have two random variables $X,Y$ with support on $A=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ such that $\mathbb{E}[X^k]=\mathbb{E}[Y^k]$ for all $1\le k\le n$, does this imply that $\mathbb{E}[X^k]=\mathbb{E}[Y^k]$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$?

It seems like this should be true to me since you only have $n-1$ 'degrees of freedom' in creating such random variables but I'm not sure how I would go about proving this. I've thought about trying to create a degree $n-1$ polynomial with coefficients related to $p_X(a_i)-p_Y(a_i)$ and showing that the $a_i$ are zeros to show $X=Y$ in distribution but I haven't been able to make this work out. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p_j := P(X=a_j)$ and $q_j := P(Y=a_j)$.
Suppose we have $\sum_{j=1}^n p_j a_j^k = \sum_{j=1}^n q_j a_j^k$ for all $1 \le k \le \color{blue}{n-1}$.
These relationships (along with the "zero moment" condition $\sum_{j=1}^n p_j = \sum_{j=1}^n q_j$) can be written as
$$A p = A q$$
where $p=(p_1, \ldots, p_n)$ and $q=(q_1, \ldots, q_n)$ are column vectors containing the probabilities associated with $X$ and $Y$, and where $A$ is [the transpose of] an $n \times n$ [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) induced by the $a_1, \ldots, a_n$. If the $a_i$ are distinct, you can show the matrix $A$ is invertible (e.g. by looking at the formula for the determinant of a Vandermonde matrix), and thus $p=q$.

Comment: It appears that this argument only requires the first n-1 moments to be equal, is that correct?

Comment: @RobertB.Marshall Barring any mistakes I have overlooked, yes it seems so. I edited my answer quite a bit after you accepted it earlier.

Comment: @RobertB.Marshall - your original intuition about polynomials is correct: it just shows up on the "other" side of the matrix $A$ here.  Consider any $n-1$ degree (or less) polynomial $t(x)$ with $n$ coefficients represented by row-vector $t$.  Now consider the row vector $tA$, whose $j$th element is $[tA]_j = t(a_j)$.  Now imagine all the $a_j$s are distinct and yet $tA=0$.  This means the polynomial has $n$ distinct roots, which can only happen if it is the zero polynomial $t=0$.  I.e., $\forall t: tA = 0 \Rightarrow t = 0$, which is only true if $A$ is non-singular.